# Tag Proposal: [asymmetric]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, king-of-the-hill, cops-and-robbers

I've cooked up a few [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenges, mostly in the sandbox, and a few of them are asymmetric in nature.

They're not really [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) because it's not really about cracking a code, nor is it a meta-challenge that you might expect from the more common idea of Cops and Robbers (normally, these target a specific submission and crack it by a certain deadline). The roles in this kind of KotH are also distinctly different and require completely different strategies and code.

There are currently only [2 challenges currently tagged as both](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers+king-of-the-hill) [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) and [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers). But there are also a couple of other challenges in the same vein with asymmetric roles:

- [Liars and Guessers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/220510/45613) - Liars and Guessers have different goals and play a different role in the game
- [Red vs. Blue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48353/45613) - Each team has slightly different movement options.
- Sandbox: [The Ever-Changing Labyrinth](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19194/45613) - Maze masters and Adventurers have completely different roles

## Options

I see a few courses of action here:

### A new tag: [asymmetric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymmetric)

Pros:

- Represents a distinctly different idea from what CnR challenges most frequently represent, which usually require one role to go head-to-head with a specific submission from the other role

Cons:

- Creates a new tag that may potentially be confused with [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)
- There are not very many challenges of this nature
- Probably only makes sense when paired with [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) and might be confusing in other contexts.

  - Might be remedied by calling it [multiple-roles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-roles) instead, but this might be too similar to [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

### Use [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) for this purpose

... And tag all currently untagged challenges accordingly

Pros:

- Re-uses an existing tag

Cons:

- This would exclude any challenges with cooperative but asymmetric roles, though no challenges of this nature exist, to my knowledge.
- The culture and typical usage of this tag would create an alternate meaning for this tag that only applies when paired with KotH

### Remove the [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) tag from the two challenges also tagged [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)

These two tags should be mutually exclusive. Some KotHs simply have multiple roles.

Pros:

- No new tag
- No overloading of an existing tag with a strong culture of a specific meaning that isn't compatible in an immediately obvious way.

Cons:

- No way to distinguish KotHs with multiple asymmetric roles.

---

Anyway, discuss

Comment: The way I think of it, where did we get the name KoTH in the first place? To me, the etymology at least points me in the direction that KoTHs are by definition, symmetric? Asymmetric KoTHs are thus effectively a special one-time occurrence and don't require a new tag. Of course, it's probably just my ignorance speaking here.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 Koths aren't symmetric or asymmetric, [cops and robbers] challenges are (in the style of "Cops do X, Robbers try to undo X"). Asymmetric CnRs typically have to be somewhat KOTH-based, otherwise they're either too unclear as to what the roles are, or they just end as typically CnR challenges

Answer (score 5):

### Create the [asymmetric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymmetric) tag

Currently, [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) is used to serve this role, which is an imperfect fit. Robbers typically just aim to crack specific cop answers in standard CnR challenges - they can, to all intents and purposes, ignore other Robbers (and cops can ignore other cops)

[asymmetric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymmetric) would cover challenges where:

- there are two or more groups of answers (for example, [dwarves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230965/play-thud-dwarf-edition) and [trolls](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230966/play-thud-troll-edition)) which are interacting with each other, and
- within each group of answers, there is interaction between the answers

This second point is the key distinguisher between [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) and [asymmetric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymmetric) - if the answers in each group don't interact with each other, it's not [asymmetric](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymmetric).

Note: I feel like the name "asymmetric" doesn't appropriately present this key point. It works, but I feel like it could be a better name. Feel free to make suggestions

Answer (score 0):

## The tag has now been created

as a result of [a discussion in The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/conversation/tagasymmetric).

As caird coinherringaahing points out, we can always delete it if we feel it's no longer relevant.